# Native JavaScript Library for Document Conversion

Tags: java, javascript, html

I know there are tons of library for converting between documents format for PHP, Java etc.

But I wanted to know if there is any pure javascript libary for converting between document formats.

I want the conversion to take place at client side itself without sending it to the server.

Is it possible or is it farfetched?

Comment: There are way too many reasons to avoid doing this client side in the browser. Use AJAX on one of the many aqvailable APIs: eg. http://en.pdf24.org/javascript-pdf-api.html

Comment: why should i avoid client side. Can you please give some reasons?

Comment: It's literally too broad without knowing exactly why you want to do it this way? If you tell me what you're trying to achieve, I can give you specific details as to the risks / pitfalls involved in that process. For instance, how big are the documents you are converting? What are your origin and target formats? These thignswill greatly affect performance of the browser (modern browsers can cop a pretty decent hiding but you shouldn't forget you are a LONG way from native), information type will affect your security concerns and the suitability of client side for those reasons. the list goes on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. For example you can use [jsPDF](https://code.google.com/p/jspdf/) to generate PDF documents. But it is generally not advisable to do document conversion on the client side due to all the unknown variables (i.e. doc versions, client computer capacity, etc....) A server library meant for document conversion will have much more robust handling of all the various conditions that may arise when trying to process documents. Hope that helps!